# Jquery asp.net 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-2.0

Is jquery compatible with asp.net 2.0...i mean can i use jquery in asp.net 2.0??

Comment: See [How to use JQuery AJAX with ASP.net 2.0 ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342650/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-with-asp-net-2-0).

Comment: I have worked on jquery ...but using java ....i am new to aps.net...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it freely, I mean that you will have no Javascript problems with that, but don't expect interaction with ASP.NET controls of any kind.

Comment: can u elaborate a bit more with "interaction with controls" ...u mean i can use the values in a asp text box through jquery....ebven if i get it with the client id??

Comment: You can select and use a value of a text box and do easy stauff but you will find problems when using data inside a UpdatePanel for example. I think ASP.NET is not designed to use an external JS library but it will be useful with easy modifications

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed it is. I am using it at the moment

Comment: can you give me a link to any kick start tutorials??

Comment: @abbas, what do you want to achieve with it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  jQuery is a javascript framework that runs on the client (in a web browser).  Asp.net is a web development framework that executes it's scripting on a web server.